# List into other List jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I have this object structure, to use like Java Bean in mi jasper report,

```
public class Person{
   private String name;
   private String lastname;
   private List<Job> jobs;
}

public class Job{
   private String jobName;
   private String companyName;
   private List<Reponsability> responsabilities;
}
```

*All class with corresponding `setters` and `getters`*

When I create a list into jasper report I define the **"job list"** `JRDataSource expression` this way:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{jobs})
```

Now I want to create another list, **"responsibilities list"** on the **"job list"**, the question is:

How can I define the data source to get the corresponding job to pass into the `JRDataSource Expression`?

I imagine something like this:

```
new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(${jobs}.get($index).getResponsabilities())
```

but I can't get it work this

Comment: See also: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html

Comment: Your are iterating the records correct?, not trying to get a specific index? (but the records related to current jobs?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to do this:

Into the list, I created a variable called **jobInstance**

```
    <field name="jobInstance" class="com.mypackage.example.Job">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
```

Then when I set the datasource for **responsibilities** list did this:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{jobInstance}.getResponsabilities())
```

References: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/508346/getting-current-object

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I had list inside the a bean like Job bean that mentioned. I added the list for this pojo and getting the values as expected. Now the issue is there a list inside this , not getting how can I display this in the table I created for Job.

Comment: Where we need to add the field in jasper report for the list which is in another list ? Please help.

Comment: Depends on what you want. I use the example of the list because at that moment I needed a list o person and for every person, I needed to show his job responsibilities too. What exactly you want?